# Cannot unpack request JSON with CSRF on

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, flask, csrf

Ajax request can be unpacked as long as `@csrf.exempt` is set. As soon as I comment it out, `request.get_json(force=True)` fails. Putting it through debugger:

`(Pdb) p request._cached_json
'Request' object has no attribute '_cached_json'`

Template code:

```
var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token);
        }}});
```

Dispatching the request:

```
save()
{
    $.post("/save", JSON.stringify({'name': 'aaa'}), accept_reply, "json");
}
```

Flask processing request:

```
@app.route('/save', methods=("POST",))
#@csrf.exempt
def save():
    order_data = request.get_json(force=True)
    return jsonify({"status": "ok"})
```

When `@csrf.exempt` is commented out, `request` has no attribute `_cached_json`: `request.get_json(force=True)` raises exception, while `request.get_json()` simply returns None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that Flask requires a "Content-Type": "application/json" header to recognized that you are posting a JSON package, otherwise I believe it thinks you're sending urlencoded form data.

I've found that I can't use any jQuery "convenience" AJAX methods if I am looking to POST JSON data to Flask.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ url_for('.update_formulary_mb') }}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({id: state.config, update: records}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
});
```

#### Edit 9/1/2017

As it turns out you **can** use jQuery `post()` method if all of your XHR requests require the same parameters using jQuery's [**ajaxSetup()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) method:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    contentType: "application/json"
});
```

This will pass common parameters to **all** ajax and derivative methods within the scope of it's use... so it works well if you're following the same pattern in all of your XHR calls on a page...

Comment: Thank you, this works! However, there is a canonical way to adjust jQuery.post():  `$.ajaxSetup({contentType: "application/json"})`. Ajax Setup is also used to prepend `X-CSRFToken`, so I got $.post() to work with Flask with minimal effort.

Comment: ok great! I will add a note to the answer to capture this... I had never seen the `ajaxSetup()` method...great if you're XHR requests all follow a similar pattern